# How can I get colored keyword labels in readme.md on GitHub?

Tags: github, label, keyword, readme

This might be a stupid question, but I can not figure out how to add colored keyword labels to my `readme.md` file

See example of what I am after here
https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap

How to get similar to these that you can see on the page at the link above:
CDNJS NPM Version Build Status Coverage Status License

Answer (score 10):

Those aren't labels - they're "badges" provided by CDNJS, NPM etc.

They're really just image links that happen to look like colored text. Here's the markdown involved for CDNJS for example:

```
[![CDNJS](https://img.shields.io/cdnjs/v/reactstrap.svg)](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/reactstrap)
```

A lot of CI and package systems have instructions for how to embed badges like this. For example, the Travis docs for the feature are [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/).

It looks like [shields.io](https://shields.io/) is a service dedicated to providing images like this for all kinds of services.

There's nothing particularly magical about this, of course. They're just Markdown image links. You could link to any image, including one generated by your own server somewhere, if you want. It's just that CI and packaging systems have adopted this pretty widely for use in GitHub and similar systems.

Comment: Thanks Daisy for the detailed reply. It was very helpful, and I shall have a look at shields.io!

Comment: @ThomasThorstensson: I can't say I'd seen it before today. It's always nice to learn something new when answering a question!

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, can you please accept the answer. Thanks